# Java, Spring : Finding objects within a given time-frame not working after adding time-zone to java.sql.Timestamp

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring-MVC project in which I have a `GroupNotes` object which I am trying to search for within a given time-frame to inform user. The time was originally saved in Postgresql `Timestamp object without timezone`. Later we added timezone to it. But since we have done that, we couldn't find any objects, the DAO code is not working. We modified the PostgreSQL column as well as model definition for migrating to with time zone.

DAO code :

```
@Override
    public List<GroupNotes> findGroupNotesWithExpiryInTwelveHours() {
        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long plus47Hours = currentTime + (11 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        Timestamp plus47HoursTS = new Timestamp(plus47Hours);

        long plus48Hours = currentTime + (12 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        Timestamp plus48HoursTS = new Timestamp(plus48Hours);

        Query query = session.createQuery("from GroupNotes as gn where gn.zugwisenPersonId!=:val and gn.noteTarget > :from and gn.noteTarget < :to");
        query.setParameter("val", 0);
        query.setParameter("from", plus47HoursTS);
        query.setParameter("to", plus48HoursTS);
        return query.list();
    }
```

GroupNotes object :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "groupnotes")
public class GroupNotes implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @Column(name = "notetarget",columnDefinition = "timestamp with time zone")
    private java.sql.Timestamp noteTarget;

// Other columns
}
```

Service layer method calling the code :

// Also, can someone tell me if below script will execute every 2 hours?

```
  @Override
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0/2 * * *")
    public void checkForZugweisedNotesAndSendEmail() {

  List<GroupNotes> twelveHourList = this.groupNotesService.findGroupNotesWithExpiryInTwelveHours();
            for (GroupNotes groupNotes : twelveHourList) {
// Perform operations
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you want to use hard way.I believe you already changed data type in your postgre side to `timestamp`.So you just need to change you entity like this

```
@Column(name = "notetarget",columnDefinition = "timestamp with time zone")
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)//declare timestamp
private Date noteTarget;//no need to use java.sql.Timestamp
```

In your method just use date and set particular times accordingly likes

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,11);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE,0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND,0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND,0);

Date plus47Hours  = cal.getTime();
```

And then you can change your query simply

```
from GroupNotes as gn where gn.zugwisenPersonId!=:val and gn.noteTarget between :from and :to
```

Comment: I had written only Timestamp, but while posting the model I wrote java.sql.Timestamp for better understanding. I will add the temporal annotation and change the DAO code as you suggested. Will infrom you. Thanks.. :-)

Comment: @WeareBorg java.util.Date is better than java.sql.Timestamp in your condition.My opinion java.sql.Timestamp is hard to manipulate. Date object can retrieve time stamp too.

Comment: Hi, Thank you, but I still don't get any objects back with the query. Any idea? I had set the between 0 to 60 hours, and the object was at 12 hours, but still wasn't found by the query. Thanks.